# Write a subprogram that calculates n!. While using this subprogram make a program that calculates (a+b)!

Tags: c++, if-statement, count, return, factorial

My task is

> Write a subprogram that calculates `n!`. While using this subprogram make a program that calculates `(a+b)!`.

I wrote the following code:

```
using  namespace  std;
int f(int n) {
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
        f=f*i;
    }
    return f;
}
int main() {
    int a,b;
    cout<<"a=";
    cin>>a;
    cout<<"b=";
    cin>>b;
    cout<<"factorial of a+b="<<(a+b)*f;
    return 0;
}
```

And I get this error when I compile:

```
 In function 'int f(int)':
7:27: error: invalid operands of types 'int(int)' and 'int' to binary 'operator*'
8:8: error: invalid conversion from 'int (*)(int)' to 'int' [-fpermissive]
 In function 'int main()':
16:34: error: invalid operands of types 'int' and 'int(int)' to binary 'operator*'
17:9: error: expected '}' at end of input
```

Comment: Look at the error messages again. Look at the code where `f` is used. Look at the code where `f` is defined. Do that a few times and I'm sure you will see the problem.

Comment: Some indentation in your code would be helpful.

Comment: to elaborate on Joachim comment, f in defined as a function and you use it as  an int in the loop, as well as return f!!

Comment: From your definition of `f`, and the expression `(a+b)*f`, I would suggest that you get a [good book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). If you already have one, open it and read it again. Pay particular attention to the text that isn't code, as it explains the code.

Comment: Welcome to linear algebra, where functions are matrix and calling a function is multiplying :D.

Answer (score 1):

Here's your error

```
return f;
```

returns a function pointer of your function `f()`. Also you're using the function pointer for your calculations.

In C++ you need to declare a variable that can be used to calculate and return:

```
int f(int n) {
    int result = 1;
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++) { 
        result=result*i;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: To be fair, some languages (Basic??) use the function name as the function result within the function.

Comment: @MartinBonner _"To be fair ..."_ That was the only reason why I've answered that at all. C++ doesn't work that way, and I wanted to point the OP at that fact.

Comment: adding how to launch the function should help too

Comment: @MartinBonner - don't know about BASIC, but Pascal does that.

Comment: Good lord.  I never thought I'd forget how to write a function in FORTRAN (*), but after 20 years it appears I have.  (It has the same convention.)  *: none of this new-fangled Fortran 77 for me, I still have probably spent more time writing FORTRAN IV than any other language.